# while filling data grid view using sql reader application getting slow

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form...i am trying to fill my data grid view using sql datareader,,
while clicking button i try to fill my data grid view..
i wrote one function for filling grid view..

```
Sub filldgv()
DGVReleased.Rows.Clear()
Dim carid As String
            Dim VehicleNo As String
            Dim DriverID As String
            Dim krrt As Integer
            Dim Dt As Integer
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("IBS_fetchresleaseVehicle", con.connect)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Glocid
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                If dr("TBarcode") Is DBNull.Value Then
                    carid = ""
                Else
                    carid = dr("TBarcode")
                End If
                If dr("PlateNo") Is DBNull.Value Then
                    VehicleNo = ""
                Else
                    VehicleNo = dr("PlateNo")
                End If
                If dr("DelEcode") Is DBNull.Value Then
                    DriverID = ""
                Else
                    DriverID = dr("DelEcode")
                End If
                If dr("KRRT") Is DBNull.Value Then
                Else
                    krrt = dr("KRRT")
                End If
                If dr("DT") Is DBNull.Value Then
                Else
                    Dt = dr("DT")
                End If
                Dim row0 As String() = {carid, VehicleNo, DriverID, krrt, Dt}
                DGVReleased.Rows.Insert(0, row0)
            End While
            dr.Close()
            con.disconnect()
End Sub
```

then i am calling this function in my button click event.here first am removing all records from grid view then i am filling..while coming more records to data grid view my system is getting hang..is there any way to do this very simple manner..any help is very appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `DataGridView.Rows.AddRange`. Collect data in List(Of DataGridViewRow), then only after the loop add them to the DataGridView:

   ```
   Sub filldgv()
       Dim ListRows As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()
       Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("IBS_fetchresleaseVehicle")

       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       cmd.Connection = con.connect
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Glocid


       Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
       Dim ListRows As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()

       While dr.Read
           Dim DgvRow = New DataGridViewRow

           Dim o = {dr("TBarcode").ToString(),
                    dr("PlateNo").ToString(),
                    dr("DelEcode").ToString(),
                    If(IsDBNull(dr("KRRT")), 0, dr("KRRT")),
                    If(IsDBNull(dr("DT")), 0, dr("DT")) }

           DgvRow.CreateCells(o)
           ListRows.Add(DgvRow)
       End While

       dr.Close()
       con.disconnect()


       Dim SavedBool = DGVReleased.AllowUserToAddRows
       DGVReleased.AllowUserToAddRows = False

       DGVReleased.Rows.AddRange(ListRows.ToArray())

       DGVReleased.AllowUserToAddRows = SavedBool
   End Sub
   ```
2. Use DataTable & DataBinding, then populate DataTable in Background-Thread:

   ```
   Sub filldgv()
       Dim dt As New DataTable
       dt.Columns.Add("", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("", GetType(String))
       dt.Columns.Add("", GetType(Integer))
       dt.Columns.Add("", GetType(Integer))

       DGVReleased.DataSource = dt
       Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Populate(dt))
       ''you can replace last line with this:
       'Dim bgw = New BackgroundWorker()
       'AddHandler bgw.DoWork, Sub() Populate(dt)
       'bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
   End Sub

   Sub Populate(dt As DataTable)
       Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("IBS_fetchresleaseVehicle")

       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       cmd.Connection = con.connect
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Glocid

       Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
       While dr.Read
           Dim o = {dr("TBarcode").ToString(),
                    dr("PlateNo").ToString(),
                    dr("DelEcode").ToString(),
                    If(IsDBNull(dr("KRRT")), 0, dr("KRRT")),
                    If(IsDBNull(dr("DT")), 0, dr("DT")) }

           dt.Rows.Add(o)
       End While

       dr.Close()
       con.disconnect()
   End Sub
   ```

---

**Tip:**

instead the `if` conditions, you can use shortly [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

So instead:

```
If IsDBNull(dr("TBarcode") Then
    carid = 0
Else
    carid = dr("TBarcode")
End If
```

Written:

```
carid = If(IsDBNull(dr("TBarcode")), 0, dr("TBarcode"))
```

Thanks to @SSS: For String Fields you can simply:

```
carid = dr("TBarcode").ToString()
```

Comment: how i can collect data to in List(Of DataGridViewRow)

Comment: for collecting data i can declare like this:Dim l As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)(),,then how i can get all data to this?

Comment: I cheat and use `dr("TBarcode") & ""` to handle nulls in string fields. `Nothing & ""` returns `""`

Comment: sir,,so in this case i dont want to use this code right?:carid = If(IsDBNull(dr("TBarcode")), "", dr("TBarcode"))

Comment: sir which answer i have to check,,1 or 2?

Comment: @user3262364 I tried them both.... Second its better because the GUI is not frozen.

Comment: i checked your second answer,,that time showing error run is not member of system.threading.tasks.task

Comment: if i need to execute second answer ,,then i have to call back ground worker??

Comment: sir,,what i have to use instead to Task.Run

Comment: sir,,instead of this line Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Populate(dt)) i have to use that hided code?

Comment: @user3262364 exactly.

Comment: sir,,now not getting any error..so i vl check and let you know

Comment: in your second answer while coming to this line of code :While dr.Read
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End While  getting error:Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. i havnt give any carid = dr("TBarcode").ToString()

Comment: sir..while coming to in this row dt.Rows.Add(o) getting error:Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: yes,,now data grid view is filling,,but my data grid view column header is showing column1,column2,,...instead of that i need to show TBarcode,PlateNo..

Comment: @user3262364 here `dt.Columns.Add("XXXYourNameColumn", `

Comment: ok,,thanks a lot..after coming result to data grid view..i have to drag the row,s down then only i can able to see my result ,,so i given DGVReleased.AutoGenerateColumns = True..but still i have to drag my row to see result.